# Variadic macro in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I've seen this asked around but I need to know something very specific.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Why does the C Preprocessor remove the trailing comma before **__VA_ARGS__** here :

```
#define PRINTME(...) printf("hello", __VA_ARGS__);
```

But not here :

```
#define FINISH_IND(COUNT, ...) FINISH_X(,__VA_ARGS__, 1,2)
```

I can't seem for the life of me to figure that out.

Comment: I think comma removal is an extension and not part of the standard. Consult your vendor's manual.

Comment: It is an extension. GCC's extension is more explicit in that you must prefix two hashes, i.e. `,##__VA_ARGS__`, in order to enable removing of the trailing comma when `__VA_ARGS__` is empty. Hopefully the next standard will resolve this.